# SSHD doesn't start on Yocto. Problem with a key file

Tags: linux

I burn Yocto on my cards.
Some of it starting OK

> Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server: sshd

> Done.

Some of it not.

> Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server: sshd

> Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key

> key_load_public: invalid format

> Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key

> key_load_public: invalid format

> Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key

> key_load_public: invalid format

> Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key

> Disabling protocol version 2. Could not load host key

> sshd: no hostkeys available -- exiting.

How can I fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Well. It's quite a process.

1. Remove **all** files in /etc/ssh/
2. Run /usr/bin/ssh-keygen -A
3. Logout from a user.
4. Now you may restart and enjoy.